# How to convert every header into a permalink using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, permalinks, html-heading

I have a page containing many headers. I'd like to convert every header into a permalink of sorts using jquery/javascript.

HTML Code:

```js
$('h3').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id) { //To make sure the element has an id
    $(this).append($('<a/>', {
      href: '#' + $(this).attr('id'),
      text: '#'
    }));
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 100vh;
}

.borderedPara {
  height: 15em;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 id="Heading1">1<sup>st</sup> Heading</h3>
  <div class="borderedPara">
    1<sup>st</sup> Paragraph Content
  </div>
  <h2 id="Heading2">2<sup>nd</sup> Heading</h2>
  <div class="borderedPara">
    2<sup>nd</sup> Paragraph
  </div>
  <h3 id="Heading3">3<sup>rd</sup> Heading</h3>
  <div class="borderedPara">
    3<sup>rd</sup> Paragraph
  </div>
  <a href="#Heading4">
    <div id="Heading4">4<sup>th</sup> Heading</div>
  </a>
  <div class="borderedPara">
    4<sup>th</sup> Paragraph
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The last anchored heading is what I'd like. The whole heading should be clickable. All I get by the current jquery is a hyperlink after the heading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`.wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)...

```js
$(':header[id]').each(function() {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a')
    anchor.href = '#' + this.id
    $(this).wrapInner(anchor)
});
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 100vh;
}

.borderedPara {
  height: 15em;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 id="Heading1">1<sup>st</sup> Heading</h3>
  <div class="borderedPara">
    1<sup>st</sup> Paragraph Content
  </div>
  <h2 id="Heading2">2<sup>nd</sup> Heading</h2>
  <div class="borderedPara">
    2<sup>nd</sup> Paragraph
  </div>
  <h3 id="Heading3">3<sup>rd</sup> Heading</h3>
  <div class="borderedPara">
    3<sup>rd</sup> Paragraph
  </div>
  <a href="#Heading4">
    <div id="Heading4">4<sup>th</sup> Heading</div>
  </a>
  <div class="borderedPara">
    4<sup>th</sup> Paragraph
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: $('h3').each(function() {} converts only <h3> tags into permalinks. Is there a way to convert multiple heading tags using the same code? Something like $('h3','h2','h1','h4','h5').each(function() {}

Comment: Yes. Exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It sure does what I intended.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `$(':header')` which will select all headers for you as a shorthand selector.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith) from jQuery API

> If you want to convert header tag to link (as you did for 4th header),

```
$('h3').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id) { //To make sure the element has an id
    $(this).replaceWith(function () {
      return $('<a/>', {
        id,
        href: '#' + $(this).attr('id'),
        text: $(this).text(),
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/rkLcuvn8/)

> If you want to keep your heading tags and surround header with a link tag

```
$('h3').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id) { //To make sure the element has an id
    $(this).replaceWith(function () {
      return $('<a/>', {
        href: '#' + $(this).attr('id'),
        html: `<h3 id=${id}>` + $(this).text() + '</h3>',
      });
    });
  }
})
```

Link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/nds5mu7p/)

Comment: Anchors don't really work as permalinks. They don't scroll the page to bring the clicked heading to the top of the page.(href:'#' should contain the id of the respective heading e.g.: href:'#Heading1')

Comment: @YourPalNurav Updated answer and jsFiddle.

Comment: @YourPalNurav, Great. One advise, use anchor tag with custom style to make them look like header as well as work as hyperlink too. Or you can do something creative like on [this page](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)

Comment: [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/community/#jekyll-contributor-code-of-conduct) << This is the page I wanted to mimic. I wanted to implement it without requiring jekyll

Answer (score -1):

If you are using bootstrap 4 there is a classes for the `heading tags` like `.h6, .h5 until .h1`, Using it would be easy with the `anchor tag`

```
    <a href="mydomain.com" class="h1">This is an anchor tag with an h1 class header</a>
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the OP's question. OP has asked for conversion solution using jQuery or Javascript.